# Xamarin, Android and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, xamarin, broadcastreceiver

In my app I want to create a service to save constantly a device location. This service has to start when the phone is rebooted.

I changed the `Android.Manifest` like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application android:label="LocationTest">
    <receiver>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I also changed the `received` tag like this

```
<receiver android:permission="RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I defined a `BroadcastReceiver` like

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context, "Received intent!", ToastLength.Short).Show();

        Intent i = new Intent(context, typeof(LocationService));
        i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        context.StartService(i);
    }
}
```

I created another one from Xamarin Template like

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class BroadcastReceiverTest : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context, "New Received intent!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

If I reboot my device, no one of the `BroadcastReceiver` is fired. I don't know how I can do that. My project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/erossini/XamarinBootCompletedLocation)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem with OnBooted is that you won't be able to really see it other than in your `adb logcat`. Thus I recommend you log there instead of making a Toast. i.e. https://github.com/JonDouglas/xamarin-android-tutorials/blob/master/SystemEvents/OnBoot/OnBoot/OnBootReceiver.cs#L22

Comment: Ok, but if I start a `LocationService`, I expect this function is doing somethings, sych as track my position. But it doesn't.

Comment: Do you have a `<service>` tag in the manifest? Post that. Also remove the "premission" from the `<receiver>` tag. This is not needed there.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to find a lot of posts about this question on line, I couldn't find one with all right information. I have created a post for future reference [here](http://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/post/Xamarin-Android-and-starting-a-service-at-device-boot).

The important thing is in your `AndroidManifest`: you mustn't declare your broadcast receiver in it. If you have any services, you must declare them in it. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" 
    package="pro.wordbank.app.locationtest">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="LocationTest">
        <service android:name=".TimerService" />
        <service android:name=".LocationService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Also, it isn't possible to call `Toast.MakeText` from your Broadcast Receiver but you have to use instead `NotificationManager`.